# Alternative Font in Latex

Tags: fonts

How can I get the following font in latex? I usually the Computer Modern font in LaTeX, but I am interested to use it. In particular, I don't want to know what font it is, rather I just want to know how can I typeset in LaTeX with this font.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I voted for closure as you are just asking for the use of a certain unknown font which has been asked several times on this site. If you know the name of this font, but do not succeed using it, then let us know what you have tried with an MWE and we will help (and of course I will take back my close vote). Like this it is just a "please identify that font for me"-question and thus not appropriate for this site.

Comment: I don't know what the font is and don't want to know it. I just want to know how can I typeset in latex with this font.

Comment: With *this* very font? Then you *have to* know which font it is. If you want to use any other font, you will have to search this site for more information. There are a lot of packages around which enable a certain font for you. If you use Xe- or LuaLaTeX, you can use the package `fontspec` and load any font on your system.